# VueJS dynamic/async loading of component

Tags: asynchronous, vuejs2, vue-component

Version of Vue: 2.4.2
Version of webpack: 2.6.1

The task is... I have a component. It gets global variable, a string. And depends on this variable it should dynamically load and show one of seven quite heavy components.  It seems to me that it's not a good idea to import it all because of their weight.

Now I've made import like this:

```
import comp1 from '@/components/comp1.vue';
import comp2 from '@/components/comp2.vue';

export default {
    components: {comp1, comp2}
...
}
```

In the template we'll use it like `<comp1></comp1>` And this is not what I want. The output file is pretty big and I must move on.

I've tried made like this described in docs:

```
export default {
    components: {comp1: () => import('@/components/comp1.vue')}
...
}
```

A-a-and we have an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function comp1() {
  return __webpack_require__.e/* import() */(1).then(__webpack_require__.bind(null, 37));
}
Reason: Error: Loading chunk 1 failed.
```

The initial idea was:

```
let param = window.GLOBAL_PARAM;
let str = '@/components/comp2.vue';
switch(param) {
    case 1: {
        str = '@/components/comp1.vue';
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        str = '@/components/comp3.vue';
        break;
    }
    ...
}

export default {
    components: {comp: () => import(str)}
...
}
```

But I've got an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve async component: function comp() {
  return __webpack_require__(50)(componentPath);
}
Reason: Error: Cannot find module '@/components/comp2.vue'.
```

As I understand, I have a problem with webpack, which can't resolve "@" symbol

So, the questions are:

1. How should I fix up async loading off my components? Maybe I've made a
   sad mistake in my code?
2. How should I organize by the right way the loading one of the seven components depending on some condition (global variable or param in component). Maybe there are some webpack preferences and/or some plugins. Or maybe I should resole this problem by the other approach?

Comment: I use this syntax `components: {comp1: () => import('@/components/comp1.vue')}` in my project and it works perfectly. So what version of `vue-loader`, `vue-router`, your babel config ... you are using now?

Comment: I have no vue-router in my project. No need.
  
"vue-loader": "^13.0.4",
. babelrc:
  {
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["syntax-dynamic-import"]
}

Comment: And your `babel` and `vue-router` (version and config) and `vue-loader` config too

Comment: **there is no vue-router!** =) I have one page, not SPA, just one page. And then it's loaded I should download and show one of seven components. **package**: 
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.2",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1"
  }

Comment: There is no any config. Just babelrc-file, which text you can see above

Comment: It seems to me, there is a problem with webpack. Script prompting non existing file instead of mine **0.output_file.js** *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)*

Comment: Did you solve it? How?

Comment: No, I didn't...

Comment: Instead of using a switch to load one component or other, I would recommend you to use [`is`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) special Vue attribute. It allows you to dynamically change a generic component. Webpack automatically assumes which one you want to use, and loads it.